# How to fetch date from string format

Tags: php, string, date

We have an entry in database for an event time left as `P1DT3H53M45S`, This means 1 day, 3 hours 53 min and 45 sec. I wan to retrieve date from this format.

I can retrieve the duration left by exploding this string and the calculate and then add to current time and create date.

Is there a better way to find the duration left other than exploding ?

Comment: Regex, it would be better i guess

Comment: I don't understand how you can explode such string as `P1DT3H53M45S`. by what separator?

Comment: if it can be changed, Unix time is better IMHO

Comment: That's just a `DateInterval` format... why not pass it to its constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for explode. Use `DateInterval` instead:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1DT3H53M45S');
echo $interval->format('%d day, %h hours, %I minutes, %s seconds');
// 1 day, 3 hours, 53 minutes, 45 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

`P1DT3H53M45S` is not date, but interval. You can use `DateInterval` class to create a `DateInterval` object, from which you can format it, or add it to some of your date.

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1DT3H53M45S');
print_r($interval);

# format it
echo $interval->format('%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');

# add it to some date
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->add($interval);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/194910)</kbd>